# Error while calling stored procedure from VBA

Tags: ms-access, stored-procedures

I'm having a doozie of an error here. Okay so this is Access VBA working with a SQL Server back end - stored procedure to be precise.

I've used the following code to run stored procedures for a long time with no issues. Actually it's long so I'll paste it in if you need to see it. But the bottom line is that when I run the stored procedure from within VBA, I get the error

> ODBC: Driver Not Found and No Default Driver Specified.

With the same connection string, I get no errors anywhere else in the application, just the stored procedure. In fact, this method has been working well up to this point. I will upload an image to illustrate the issue. If anyone has a clue I'd be most grateful.

Again, using the same exact connection string works elsewhere in the application, it's only when running a stored procedure. I've run that function for a very long time (including in this application) without issue.

Thank you!

My error:

[image: My error]

`con.open` is where the error happens. The connection string and error message are similarly highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Reason is you are used Sql Server driver but actual database in MSAccess.

Please refer the below link for MSAccess connectionstring for ODBC.

https://www.connectionstrings.com/microsoft-access-accdb-odbc-driver/
https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

(OR)

Suppose you are using Sql Server then install correct sql server odbc driver version.

Comment: OP shared he was using SQL server as a backend in the question

Comment: but in tag highlighted as msaccess

Comment: Since the user is connecting _from_ microsoft access _to_ SQL server as defined in the question

Comment: Yes @ErikA is right. Perhaps I should have explained. It's an SQL Server back end with Access front end. We are using ODBC 17 driver for SQL Server, which works in all other Access/SQL databases except this one. Even within this database, I use that same connection string to relink tables and it works fine. It only causes problems when running stored procedures. I will recheck the ODBC driver versions.